# how to add a new field in django model 

Tags: mysql, django, field

this is my model :

```
class zjm_model(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=36)
```

and the table `zjm_model` has many data in my mysql , and now ,

i want to add a new field :

```
class zjm_model(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=36)
```

but , when i run `manage.py syncdb` , it show this :

```
No fixtures found.
```

so  how can i to add a new field  to my database ,

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Database migrations are not built-in to Django, so you'll need to use a third party library.  I highly recommend **[south](http://south.aeracode.org/)**.

Comment: @Tomasz: Yeah, it's pretty great.  One of these days it'll make it into django.contrib.

Answer (score 5):

south is very nice and all that, but if this is a very rare one-off thing then just fire up your favourite mysql tool and do something like: ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN wotsit VARCHAR(100) - I can't remember the exact syntax...

But +1 for south.

Answer (score -2):

You have to dump your previous data.

```
manage.py dumpdata > dump.json
```

And you can load your data after syncdb. ("c" column have to permit null)

```
manage.py loaddata dump.json
```